# Should it be easier to tell that the 'accept answer' button has been toggled?

Tags: feature-request, design

I just accepted an answer to a question, but I couldn't tell that the check mark had changed.

Looking at them side-by-side, it is easier to tell the difference, e.g.:

Unselected

[image]

Selected

[image]

But I could not tell that it was changing when I was toggling it. I thought that I might be imagining things until I saw that I had gained +2 for selecting an answer.

I have never had such doubt when using other SE sites. It might be helpful to other new users so I think that it is worth considering this change.

Comment: It could do with being a bit more contrasting - maybe a red would be better

Comment: When my laptop screen is at an angle the green and grey can be quite hard to distinguish.

Comment: Thanks for visiting meta!  You're right, the contrast all over this site is rather low.  We've had other requests for increased contrast in the links as well [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/541/link-contrast-in-comments-on-main-site-needs-to-be-fixed) and [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/499/contrast-of-hyperlinks).  I'll give our designer a ping and see if he can come check this out.

Comment: We might have a [contrast rebellion](http://contrastrebellion.com/) on our hands soon...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that could be better. My suggestion for an accepted answer: fill the circle with the olive green, and make the checkmark in it white.

Comment: Interesting note about contrast, I had no idea that there were some schematics around the header portion of the page until a few weeks ago when I plugged my laptop into a different monitor.

Comment: I think that's a great suggestion. I'll be implementing this change soon.